# Socialization gem - how to retrieve posts from users I follow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I use the [Socialization gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) and I implemented the following functionality. It works well, however, how can I get posts from users I follow?

I don't see there any method for doing that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Posts" do not exist in the socialization gem. You have to make them and then come up with a way to retreive them appropriately. It could be something like

```
Post.where(id: current_user.followers.pluck(:id))
```

The bottom line is, that gem is only the social model, not a recreation of facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I think its worth better answered. If you are using [Socialization gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) and you want to get `Posts` that are being followed by user, refer to following code.

```
user.followees(Post)
```